# How to read a character one by one from an external file, modify it, and save it back to another external file?

Tags: write-file

The purpose of this question is to learn how to read character by character of a fetched line of characters, modify it and save back to another file.

For the sake of simplicity, let's take a simple application which is encrypting an external text file with a well-known simple algorithm, "shift cipher". I can only give you a skeleton as follows, the remaining is beyond my knowledge.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{plain.txt}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
\end{filecontents*}

% shift parameter, 
% positive value moves forward (for example, 1 makes A get shifted to B),
% negative value moves backward (for example, -1 makes B get shifted to A).
\def\offset{13}

\newread\reader
\newwrite\writer

\begin{document}
\openin\reader=plain.txt
\immediate\openout\writer=encrypted.txt
    \loop
        \read\reader to \data
        \unless\ifeof\reader
            \immediate\write\writer{Do something here}
    \repeat
\immediate\closeout\writer
\closein\reader
\end{document}
```

The interesting parts I want to learn:

- How to read a character one by one from a single line fetched from an external file.
- How to modify the single character.
- How to know the number of characters in a single line fetched from an external file.

Please use the most simple method that newbies (like me) can easily digest the code.

Comment: Can we assume only A-Za-z? Digits? Spaces? Punctuation?

Comment: Would the cipher apply only to text?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Just shift according the ASCII table mapping.

Comment: @ScottH.: Yes. For the sake of simplicity and I think it is more than enough to learn what I want.

Comment: For one letter `#1` the sequence ``\char\numexpr`#1+\offset\relax`` can give you the offset letter (I have defined `\offset` as a count). Problems I encountered: Spaces, text encoding, braces in the output (decoding fails for all special characters), writing out.

Comment: Why is this a `TeX` question? There are programming languages (`awk`, `python`, `perl` ...) better suited for filters that read from a file, do something, and write the result to a file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way is to set up the uppercase table to do the translation.

This file does the encoding twice to confirm you get back to where you started (apart from white space normalisation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{plain.txt}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
\end{filecontents*}

% shift parameter, 
% positive value moves forward (for example, 1 makes A get shifted to B),
% negative value moves backward (for example, -1 makes B get shifted to A).
\def\offset{13}

\newread\reader
\newwrite\writer

\def\wrot#1{%
\uppercase{\immediate\write\writer{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter


{
\count@`a
\loop
\uccode\count@=\numexpr\count@+\offset\relax
\uccode\numexpr\count@+\offset\relax=\count@
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\count@<`n
\repeat

\count@`A
\loop
\uccode\count@=\numexpr\count@+\offset\relax
\uccode\numexpr\count@+\offset\relax=\count@
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\count@<`N
\repeat

\openin\reader=plain.txt
\immediate\openout\writer=encrypted.txt
    \loop
        \read\reader to \data
        \unless\ifeof\reader
            \expandafter\wrot\expandafter{\data}
    \repeat
\immediate\closeout\writer
\closein\reader

\openin\reader=encrypted.txt
\immediate\openout\writer=reencrypted.txt
    \loop
        \read\reader to \data
        \unless\ifeof\reader
            \expandafter\wrot\expandafter{\data}
    \repeat
\immediate\closeout\writer
\closein\reader


}

\section{plain.txt}
\input{plain.txt}

\section{encrypted.txt}
\input{encrypted.txt}

\section{reencrypted.txt}
\input{reencrypted.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This should allow all ASCII printable characters.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{plain.txt}
u&9@@^{=!{{}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gzero_new:N \g_karl_offset_int
\ior_new:N \l_karl_input_stream
\iow_new:N \l_karl_output_stream
\seq_new:N \l__karl_input_seq
\tl_new:N \l__karl_input_tl
\tl_new:N \l__karl_temp_tl
\tl_const:Nn \c_karl_space_tl { ~ }

\NewDocumentCommand{\cypher}{omm}
 {% #1 = shift #2 = input file, #3 = output file
  \IfValueT{#1}{ \int_gset:Nn \g_karl_offset_int { #1 } }
  \ior_open:Nn \l_karl_input_stream { #2 }
  \iow_open:Nn \l_karl_output_stream { #3 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l_karl_input_stream
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__karl_input_tl { ##1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__karl_input_tl { ~ } { \c_karl_space_tl }
    \karl_write:V \l__karl_input_tl
   }
  \ior_close:N \l_karl_input_stream
  \iow_close:N \l_karl_output_stream
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \karl_write:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__karl_temp_tl
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \karl_shift:n { ##1 } }
  \iow_now:NV \l_karl_output_stream \l__karl_temp_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \karl_write:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \karl_shift:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 \c_karl_space_tl
   {
    \char_set_lccode:nn { `~ } { \g_karl_offset_int + 32 }
    \tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end: \tl_put_right:Nn \l__karl_temp_tl { ~ } }
   }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { `#1 + \g_karl_offset_int > 126 }
     { \char_set_lccode:nn { `#1 } { `#1 + \g_karl_offset_int - 126 + 32 } }
     {
      \int_compare:nTF { `#1 + \g_karl_offset_int < 32 }
       { \char_set_lccode:nn { `#1 } { `#1 + \g_karl_offset_int + 126 - 32 } }
       { \char_set_lccode:nn { `#1 } { `#1 + \g_karl_offset_int } }
     }
    \tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end: \tl_put_right:Nn \l__karl_temp_tl { #1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\cypher[13]{plain.txt}{thirteen.txt}

\cypher[-13]{thirteen.txt}{plain13.txt}

\cypher[15]{plain.txt}{fifteen.txt}

\cypher[-15]{fifteen.txt}{plain15.txt}

\stop
```

#### `plain.txt`

```
u&9@@^{=!{{}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
```

#### `thirteen.txt`

```
$3FMMk*J.**,
Xn!y4"-"#$qr{#"-q|-{|#-pn!r-no|$#-qn"uv{t-}n##r!{";
Xn!y4"-"#$qr{#"-q|-{|#-pn!r-no|$#-n!!|&-#v}";
Xn!y4"-"#$qr{#"9-o(-#ur-&n(9-q|-{|#-x{|&-&un#-n-#!n{"s|!zn#v|{-zn#!v'-v";
```

#### `plain13.txt`

```
u&9@@^{=!{{}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
```

#### `fifteen.txt`

```
&5HOOm,L0,,.
Zp#{6$/$%&st}%$/s~/}~%/rp#t/pq~&%/sp$wx}v/!p%%t#}$=
Zp#{6$/$%&st}%$/s~/}~%/rp#t/pq~&%/p##~(/%x!$=
Zp#{6$/$%&st}%$;/q*/%wt/(p*;/s~/}~%/z}~(/(wp%/p/%#p}$u~#|p%x~}/|p%#x)/x$=
```

#### `plain15.txt`

```
u&9@@^{=!{{}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
```

Answer (score 4):

While I am all for LaTeX as a tool to produce beautiful books and documents this question just asks for an answer in a programming language that is much more suited for the problem.

This is an implementation in python. It is pretty verbose but I think that almost everybody with any programming knowledge who has never seen a single line of python will understand and to some degree be able to modify the following code:

```py
import string

filecontents = """Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
"""

f = open('plain.txt', 'w')
f.write(filecontents)
f.close()

def shift(char, offset):
    if char in string.lowercase:
        shifted_index = string.lowercase.index(char) + offset
        shifted_char = string.lowercase[shifted_index % len(string.lowercase)]
    elif char in string.uppercase:
        shifted_index = string.uppercase.index(char) + offset
        shifted_char = string.uppercase[shifted_index % len(string.uppercase)]
    else:
        # do nothing for special characters, otherwise we end up with non-printable
        shifted_char = char
    return shifted_char

def read_process_save(filename, offset):
    input = open('plain.txt', 'r')
    output = open('plain_shift.txt','w')
    while True:
        char = input.read(1)
        if char: 
            shifted = shift(char, offset)
            output.write(shifted)
        else:
            break
    input.close()
    output.close()

offset = 13
read_process_save('plain.txt', offset)
```

which produces the file `plain_shifted.txt` with the following contents:

```
Xney'f fghqragf qb abg pner nobhg qnfuvat cnggreaf.
Xney'f fghqragf qb abg pner nobhg neebj gvcf.
Xney'f fghqragf, ol gur jnl, qb abg xabj jung n genafsbezngvba zngevk vf.
```

If we are even more pythonic and use the 'batteries included' motto the standard library even provides rot13 encoding:

```py
from codecs import getencoder
encoder = getencoder('rot-13')
rot13string = encoder(mystring)[0]
```